# fsck failed with error code 4

Tags: fsck

I have a vcenter server that is running ubuntu and I get a 503 error when I try to access the web GUI. when I get on the ESXI host, I can console in to the server but I am getting the below error. As I am pretty green when it comes to Linux, I am not sure what it all means. I referred to the university of Google and I found a few articles saying that the fsck failed with error code 4 error means the OS needs to be rebuilt with a install disc or that the file system is corrupted. If I could get a push in the right direction, that would be great. I mainly need to know what the next steps should be.
Thank you in advance.

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btdah.png)